# SettableFuture block events of LocationListener in android

Tags: java, android, location, future

I have following question. I am writing an app using location for android 4.4-6, and I decided to wrap determining location in a handy class.

Because determining location is an async process, I return unresolved future from method of this class, listen in this class for location events, and when I get location event with correct accuracy, I resolve settablefuture (from Google guava library)

this future is used in another class, because I perform few checks (accelerometer, and then proximity, and then location) and want to process it linear and future feels natural here (I am from JavaScript world and use java only as a hobby).

however it seems that this settable future, while waiting for being resolved it block everything, and event loop is also blocked so even if phone is determining location, method onLocationChanged is never called on my location listener. of course I register it in location manager. so after 10 seconds of inactivity I resolve future with null value and sometimes after that my location listener receive update (interesting fact is sometimes it happen after unregistering it, so it suggest that event queue is blocked somehow)

anybody knows how to resolve this issue?
[Source code of this class in gitHub](https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/create-pseudo-tests/app/src/main/java/com/medziku/motoresponder/utils/LocationUtility.java)

Comment: Can you also post how you are polling the future?

Comment: https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/create-pseudo-tests/app/src/main/java/com/medziku/motoresponder/pseudotest/utilsRunners/LocationUtilityPseudoTest.java#L100


this is usage where I got problems,

Comment: Here is the real usage in the application

https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/create-pseudo-tests/app/src/main/java/com/medziku/motoresponder/logic/UserRide.java#L88

This is wrapped in async task (RespondingTask extends AsyncTask call this method only)

but I don't know it is works or not - many conditions must happen to allow app to go to this point, they are unreproductible in front of the computer - and I decided to wrote some kind of test to test modules separately. And I have problem in this "pseudotest" thing,

Answer (score 1):

You're using `GoogleServicesApi`, correct?  You should consider utilizing the `FusedLocationApi#requestLocationUpdates` and update on regular intervals.  Keep saving off each updated `Location` and then return the most recent whenever its requested.  For example, have a class implementing the `LocationListener` which has a field

```
private Location bestEstimate;
```

and a getter

```
public Location getBestEstimate() {
    return bestEstimate;
}
```

The problem with this approach is what to do when `bestEstimate` is still `null` (or `Optional#absent` since you're using Guava.)  I will leave that up to you as to how to handle it.

You can go further with this and use `SharedPreferences` to persist each location update to decrease the chance of not knowing the location between app closures, backgrounding, and whatnot.

Comment: No, I am using `android.location.LocationManager` gathered by `Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)` from my activity class. 

I need fresh location, and I cant use `bestEstimate`. When I call method getLocation, I need to gather fresh location, and wait until it will be determined with correct accurate, because I am determining speed of device in current time.


Thanks for your involvement! 
Unfortunately, it looks like you didn't respond my question. Question was: how to use settable future in way which will not block event queues. Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: Here you can find this class 

[link(https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/create-pseudo-tests/app/src/main/java/com/medziku/motoresponder/utils/LocationUtility.java)

Method getLocation return future, and in class GettingAccurateLocationProcess i have listeners which are blocked by this returned future.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't dive too deep into your code, but it appears that the `UserRide#getCurrentSpeedKmhm` method is called on the main thread.  You should start up an `AsyncTask` to run it in the background.  Then everything else will remain unblocked on the main thread.

As an alternative that may require less coding, consider using `SettableFuture#addListener` (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.html#addListener(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor))

Comment: After determining location, and receiving future, I have more things to do, so I would need to put it everything inside this listener. 

Additionally, before location, I perform process of measuring if device is shaked in similar way (future), so I would end up with cascade of add event listeners. 

That's why I prefer to keep it linear with blocking futures

Comment: I will try adding AsyncTask to the test. 

I had it in main application, but due to problems with writing instrumented tests for those Utils classes, I developed another simple app to launch manually utilities in separation from application logic, and here I forgot to add AsyncTask. 

I will wrap this process into AsyncTask and try.

Comment: I wrapped everything in async task. 

I call `Looper.prepare()` on top of its `doInBackground` method, and then I call method which make work, and then I call on the bottom `Looper.loop()`. 

Accelerometer works with promise - I discovered that accelerometer on my phone doesn't work with turned off screen. But for Location - I can't make it work. It keep returning me location updates after setting the future value.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "keep returning me location updates after seeing the future value"

Comment: setting, not seeing. 

I mean that until I will not call future.set, onLocationUpdate on listener is not called. Then when app call future.set(null) on timeout (I have timer - if it took more than 10 sec then break the process and resolve with null and unregister handlers), after that I got bunch of updates

Comment: Hard to debug with just words, going to need to see code.

Comment: https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/create-pseudo-tests/app/src/main/java/com/medziku/motoresponder/utilitiesrunner/utilityrunners/LocationUtilityRunner.java

https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/create-pseudo-tests/app/src/main/java/com/medziku/motoresponder/utilitiesrunner/UtilitiesRunner.java

https://github.com/orzechowskikamil/motoresponder/blob/create-pseudo-tests/app/src/main/java/com/medziku/motoresponder/utils/LocationUtility.java

Please look what's wrong with this because I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Wow! finally I made it working. It looks like I need 3 threads.

1st - UI thread (activity)
2nd - my AsyncTask where I ask for promise and wait until it will be resolved. In this thread LocationUtillity returns unresolved promise, and launch 3rd thread which will make all work. This thread get blocked by unresolved promise.
3rd - new Thread which will listen for locationUpdates, because it's not separate and it can listen for events, and when correct event come, it resolve promise and by resolving promise, unblock 2nd thread. 

I am from JS world, here everything is async so it was unnatural

Comment: Thank you for giving correct inspiration for resolving this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it working.

It looks like I need 3 threads. 1st - UI thread (activity)

2nd - my AsyncTask where I ask for future and wait until it will be resolved. In this thread LocationUtillity returns unresolved future, and launch 3rd thread which will make all work. This thread get blocked by unresolved future, until it will resolved (result of the future is required later so thread must be blocked)

3rd - new Thread which will listen for locationUpdates. Because it's separate and it can listen for events, and when correct event come, it resolve future and by resolving future, and unblock 2nd thread which can proceed with it's calculation.

Previously with UI thread and async task it was working like this:

In async task, after registering to location updates, looper must be called. When looper.loop() called, thread gets blocked, and method returning future was not returning it, so rest of the program never executed.

OR

When I called looper.loop() after receiving the future, the location listener never received updates, because looper was actually called after resolving the future with the timeout value (which happens always after 10 seconds without proper location updates).

So the solution was to use three separate threads for every path of execution.

I am from JS world, here everything is async so it was unnatural for me that I need to create so much threads to parallelize it, I didn't know that all of this things should be separated in separated threads to not block each other.